# having trouble overwriting querystring with history.PushState

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I can't figure out how to correctly use push state. I'm getting weird url's like so:

`http://website.net/home?http://website.net/home=undefined&tab=browse`

And can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try. I need domain/path to stay the same, I just want to rebuild the querystring (which I do in another function) then apply `history.pushState()`

Here's a basic look at the code, abbreviated to show the problem in question.

```
var sk = {
    //push function
    pushState: function(qs,callback){
        var i = 0, uri = '';
        $.each(qs,function(k,v){
            if(k=="" || v==""){
                delete qs[k];
            }
        });
        $.each(qs,function(k,v){
            if(i == 0){
                uri +='?';
            }else{
                uri +='&';
            }
            uri +=k+'='+encodeURIComponent(v);
            i++;
        });
        var obj ={ Title: $('title').html(), Url: uri }
        if(typeof callback !== "undefined" && callback !== false){
            obj[callback[0]] = callback[1];
        }
        history.pushState(obj,obj.Title,obj.Url);
    },

    //parse current url and return querystring
    getQSvars : function(){
        var vars = {}, hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    },
};
```

Comment: what is parameter `qs` made of

Comment: an object of property / values to be changed in the url. for example if i'm at `website.net/?tab=create` and click on tab `browse` url should then say `website.net/?tab=browse`. this obviously should work for as many query string paramters as required, which is why i take the liberty of parsing the querystring into an object from the url before passing it into this function. in this way values can overwrite any previous value.

Comment: I ask, because it looks like one of the keys passed is the current URL

Comment: @JaromandaX that turned out to be the problem. when QueryString is empty, parse function returns object with key `window.location.hash` that has value of `undefined.`

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added the parse function, without fixing it. if you want to answer the question now, i will award you the votes and accept the answer.